# Як перекласти слово "присоска"

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів

Є безліч дрібниць, що кріпляться до скла або іншої гладкої поверхні за допомогою силіконового кружечка, який називають присоскою. [Словник А.Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%CC%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on) надає такий переклад:

> ***Присо́ска*** –
>   1) присмо́ктування, присиса́ння; оконч. присмокта́ння, присса́ння;

Але це все назви процесу, а не предмета.
Варіант *"присосок"* перекладається як ботанічний і зоологічний термін — *ссальце, присисальце*, що несе в собі значення *"ссати"* — смоктати, що також недоречне навіть за умови певної метафоричності.

Чи є в українській мові усталена назва такого кріплення?

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, що *при* тут є приростом, тому рішив оглянути спочатку *соска* — отримав від [словника Штепи](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) *липка*, отже матимемо **прилипка**.

Answer (score 0):

Згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA) варіант "присосок" може вживатися як і для того, щоб позначити пристрій, так і для позначення органу. Саме тому такий варіант можна вживати для перекладу даного слова.

Comment: тоді чому запозичене з російської присосок? Відповідник російського сосать - ссати або смоктати. Є українське питомі слова для позначення в зоології органу присисання комах, наведені у запитанні,